# How to create IAM policies with sparkleformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am attempting to use [sparkleformation](http://www.sparkleformation.io/docs/) to create an IAM policy, but I don't know what dynamic to call and am not sure if my template is formatted correctly. [Sparkleformation](http://www.sparkleformation.io/docs/) also offers next to nothing in terms of error messages, which only makes this harder to debug.

Heres the policy I want to create in sparkleformation

```
{
    "Version": "2010-09-09",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*",
                "ec2:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and here is my current template to create this

```
SparkleFormation.new(:my_policy, :provider => :aws) do
  AWSTemplateFormatVersion '2010-09-09'
  description 'my policy'

  dynamic!(:aws_iam_policy, :test_group) do
    properties do
      policies array!(
        -> {
          policy_name "mypolicy"
          policy_document do
                version "2012-10-17"
                statement do
                  effect "Allow"
                  resource "*"
                  action array!(
                    "s3:Get*",
                    "s3:List*",
                    "ec2:*"
                  )
                end
            end
        }
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Running this gives out the following error:

```
$ bundle exec sfn create test --file sparkleformation/templates/my-policy.rb 
[Sfn]: Callback template stack_policy: starting
[Sfn]: Callback template stack_policy: complete
[Sfn]: SparkleFormation: create
[Sfn]:   -> Name: test
[Sfn]: Events for Stack: test
Time                      Resource Logical Id   Resource Status      Resource Status Reason   
2017-11-08 20:36:24 UTC   test                  CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   User Initiated           
2017-11-08 20:36:28 UTC   TestGroupIamPolicy   CREATE_FAILED        Encountered unsupported property Policies                              
2017-11-08 20:36:29 UTC   test                     CREATE_FAILED        The following resource(s) failed to create: [TestGroupIamPolicy].  
[FATAL]: Create of new stack test: FAILED
ERROR: RuntimeError: Stack did not reach a successful completion state.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the proper structure.  Note that unlike roles or groups you don't set a policy array, just the document.  Also a policy cannot be created on its own it must be attached to something by setting at least one value in a roles, groups and/or users array:

```
SparkleFormation.new(:my_policy, :provider => :aws) do
  AWSTemplateFormatVersion '2010-09-09'
  description 'my policy'

  dynamic!(:aws_iam_policy, :test_group) do
    # at least one of these must be set roles, groups, users
    roles array!(
      "role1",
      "other-role"
    )

    users array!(
      "myuser"
    )

    policy_name "mypolicy"
    policy_document do
      version "2012-10-17"
      statement do
        effect "Allow"
        resource "*"
        action array!(
          "s3:Get*",
          "s3:List*",
          "ec2:*"
        )
      end
    end

  end
end
```